# Fake job given as appeasement?

Tags: single-word-requests

I want to describe: a job-position that is given to someone as a way to appease the person, but the position holds no real function.

Context:

> He was, due to his importance to the secret project, offered an honorary ____ with disproportionally lucrative payment.

The job is given by the authority to the person as a way to basically bribe him with undeserved salary, because he won't be given any real task. The emphasis here is payment, and not power, so "figurehead" would be inappropriate.

Comment: Don't the terms 'honorary' and 'disproportionately lucrative' already convey the idea, even if the blank is filled with something like *job* or *position*? Aren't you really seeking a word that would convey this idea **by itself**, without such qualifications?

Comment: There are many references on this site to [sinecure](https://english.stackexchange.com/search?q=sinecure)

Comment: I agree with @jsw29 - the idea is already expressed in the OP's sentence, and a more likely word to fill the blank would be something like "directorship" which *doesn't* in itself repeat the idea of "money for nothing".

Comment: Tempted to answer **foreign ambassador** but I'll bite my tongue...

Comment: Sop may be good;(as in offered a position as a sop) although it isn't valueless in terms of salary the position itself is worthless, and it's being given to keep the person happy. had it as answer, but then deleted as I saw that it doesn't fill the blank, although may be of use so adding as comment

Answer (score 60, accepted):

The word you're looking for is

> **sinecure** *noun*
>   1. A position or office that requires little or no work but provides a salary.

[TFD Online](https://www.thefreedictionary.com/sinecure).

Comment: Wikipedia seems to have an article on that word explaining its origin and its uses https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sinecure.

Answer (score -7):

You could maybe use

> **pencil pusher**
>   (informal, often derogatory) One who does routine office work; someone involved mainly in paperwork.

https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/pencil_pusher

Comment: That implies neither honorary nor lucrative (rather the opposite).

Comment: This does not fit what the OP is looking for at all. Paper pushers DO work, and it is not a position given to appease them.